# CarrierWave on rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rails-admin

I'm trying put a fileUploader to upload some files to database.

I followed the steps on the [rails_admin wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CarrierWave) of but couldn't make it work. Specifically the fileUploader don't appear on view. Can anyone offer suggestions?

```
class Peca < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :documento, DocumentoUploader
  belongs_to :cliente

  has_many :referencias, class_name: "Peca", foreign_key: "referencia_peca_id"
  belongs_to :referencia_peca, class_name: "Peca"

  RailsAdmin.config do |config|
      config.model 'Peca' do
          list do
              field :nome
              field :created_at
          end

          update do
              exclude_fields :referencias
          end

          create do
               exclude_fields :referencias
          end
      end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a typo, your code is `mount_uploaders`. It should be `mount_uploader`. As the [wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CarrierWave) says.

Comment: You also have a typo- it should be `mount_uploader`, not `mount_uploder`.